# Detecting Connectivity Changes Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

Currently I am using **Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity** to check my internet connection. I am using the code below to check if there is an internet before doing a transaction. How can I check if there is a change in my internet connection across my forms? For example, I have two(2) forms **Login Form** and **Main Menu** regardless what form I am currently in when I turn of my the Wifi of my device it will display an alert prompting me that there is no internet connection. How can I achieve that?

```
var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

//Check if there is an internet connection
if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
   DisplayAlert("Ok", "Connected", "Ok");
}
else {
   DisplayAlert("Error", Connected, "Ok");
}
```

I tried to use this code from the documentation of Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity but I dont know how to use this and where to put this

```
public class ConnectivityTest
{
   public ConnectivityTest()
   {
       // Register for connectivity changes, be sure to unsubscribe when finished
       Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
   }

   void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs  e)
   {
       var access = e.NetworkAccess;
       var profiles = e.Profiles;
   }
}
```

My code for syncing

```
public async void FirstSyncUser(string host, string database, string contact)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            var sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE ContactID = '" + contact + "'";
            var getUser = conn.QueryAsync<UserTable>(sql);
            var resultCount = getUser.Result.Count;

            //Check if the user has been sync
            if (resultCount < 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    syncStatus.Text = "Syncing User Data";

                    var link = Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=8qApc8";
                    string contentType = "application/json";
                    JObject json = new JObject
                    {
                        { "ContactID", contact }
                    };

                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(link, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        if(content != "")
                        {
                            var userresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserData>>(content);
                            for (int i = 0; i < userresult.Count; i++)
                            {
                                syncStatus.Text = "Syncing User Data " + (i + 1) + " out of " + userresult.Count;

                                var item = userresult[i];
                                var contactID = item.ContactID;
                                var userID = item.UserID;
                                var userPassword = item.UserPassword;
                                var userType = item.UserType;
                                var userStatus = item.UserStatus;
                                var lastSync = Convert.ToDateTime(item.LastSync);
                                var serverUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ServerUpdate);
                                var mobileUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.MobileUpdate);

                                var user = new UserTable
                                {
                                    ContactID = Convert.ToInt32(contactID),
                                    UserID = userID,
                                    UserPassword = userPassword,
                                    UserType = userType,
                                    UserStatus = userStatus,
                                    LastSync = lastSync,
                                    ServerUpdate = serverUpdate,
                                    MobileUpdate = mobileUpdate
                                };

                                await conn.InsertAsync(user);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Proceed to next function
                            FirstSyncContacts(host, database, contact);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write("Syncing User Error " + ex.Message);
                }

                //Proceed to next function
                FirstSyncContacts(host, database, contact);
            }
            //If not get the user
            else
            {
                SyncUser(host, database, contact);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Syncing User Error " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It use it globally, set up the handler at the App(lication) level. Otherwise add/remove the handler within the Page lifecycle events (to avoid duplication, define a Page subclass with those events and then use that subclass as the subclass for all your other Pages.)

Comment: @SushiHangover can you show me?

Comment: @SushiHangover can you show me how and where do I put this? In order to use it globally

Answer (score 2):

> can you show me how and where do I put this? In order to use it globally

Here is an example of using Essentials.Connectivity at the Forms' Application level via the OnStart, OnSleep and OnResume overrides

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    ~~~~

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

    void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page page;
        if (MainPage is NavigationPage)
        {
            page = ((NavigationPage)MainPage).CurrentPage;
        }
        else
        {
            page = MainPage;
        }
        page.DisplayAlert("Status", e.NetworkAccess.ToString(), "OK");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer last question, what if instead of a display alert I want to execute a **public async void FirstSyncUser(string host, string database, string contact)** the purpose of checking the internet changes so that I can sync the two databases

Comment: Please see updated question above how can I execute that instead of a display alert?

Comment: @lootverge Just call `FirstSyncUser` vs calling DisplayAlert, passing the appropriate parameters

Comment: Where do I call FirstSyncUser? iniside void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)?

Comment: @lootverge yes, assuming you want to check `e.NetworkAccess` equals Internet first .. `if (e.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet) { ... }`

Comment: I am getting an error **System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000004 (from typeref, class/assembly Xamarin.Essentials.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs, Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)**

Comment: @lootverge Do you have Xamarin.Essentials added to each of your application projects?

Comment: Not all I will add it

Comment: I have added it still there is an error System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000005 (from typeref, class/assembly Xamarin.Essentials.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs, Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)

Comment: @sushuHangover how can I fix this?